# Spring Roo Database.properties file

Tags: hibernate, spring-roo

Hi I am unable to connect to database in spring roo project. My error is ERROR 
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No database selected

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query;
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

My  Database.properties file

```
database.password=test@
database.url=jdbc\:mysql\://yahoo.com:3306
database.username=arv_aaa    
database.schemaNames=ar@1
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: @user506129: please check the edit I made. the `database.url` looks strange

Answer (score 5):

Just fix the following line:

```
database.url=jdbc\:mysql\://yahoo.com:3306
```

And add some data base the following way:

```
database.url=jdbc\:mysql\://yahoo.com:3306/mydb
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Problem is solved I am using the mysql server IP instead of url. It works now thank you